# Mach-O file structure

Tags: mach-o

I used Xcode 14.3.1 and iOS version 16.2.I wanted to understand the process of Mach-O binding symbols, but the offset address of the NSLog function is very different from others:
[image]

other's:
[image]

I looked through a lot of sources but I couldn't find the answer

Comment: What exactly are you confused about? What is "very different"?